# Using tipa with XeLaTeX fontspec and real UTF-8 characters

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Following on from the post [Using TIPA with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64830/using-tipa-with-fontspec), how would I go about using IPA glyphs with XeLaTeX using the actual Unicode UTF-8 characters instead of using the tipa re-encoding? That is, using tipa you can say

```
\textipa{f@"nEtIks}
```

but I'd like just to be able to type

```
fə′nɛtɪks
```

or even

```
\textipa{fə′nɛtɪks}
```

that is, using the actual UTF-8 characters, not the tipa symbolic notation. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try? (Spoiler: it works)

Comment: @Sverre it doesn't work with the default (lm) fonts though, missing characters in that case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, but since the OP explicitly mentions `fontspec`, `xelatex`, Unicode, and UTF-8, I take it for granted that the OP knows how to load unicode fonts with `fontspec`. (Isn't the default font `cm`, btw?)

Comment: @Sverre no, not with fontspec switches to lm

Comment: This question is essentially a cross between [Accessing IPA characters when using Charis SIL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89618/42880), which is about how to input UTF-8 characters when using `fontspec` and `xelatex`, and [Proper way to use LaTeX fonts in XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115284/42880). The added dimension is that [`tipa` is the only font with T3 encoding](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165870/42880).

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have a font with the characters, why not?

[image]

The above being the output from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

fə′nɛtɪks

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point. I was hoping to be able to use the tipa fonts but I guess I'll need to write a remapping shim to do that.

Comment: @PeterFlynn The TIPA fonts are included in `cm-unicode`.